# ng-click with thymleaf expression, what is the correct syntax

Tags: angularjs, thymeleaf

I am writing `ng-click` with a condition which checks a condition from thymleaf property.

```html
th:ng-click=" $(#thymleafProperty + '== 1 ||' + #thymleafProperty + '== 2 )' + ? someJsMethod() : otherJsMethod() "
```

it is a syntax error, please help me

Comment: I'm not familiar with thymleaf, but why not leave the ng-click bind as single function and split off to the desired logic-function inside the click-function?

Comment: @MarvinSmit yes, that is another solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to it. Thymleaf expression has to be enclosed in curly braces, I was missing the curly braces.

```html
th:ng-click=" ${#thymleafProperty + '== 1 ||' + #thymleafProperty + '== 2 ) ? someJsMethod() : otherJsMethod()' }"
```